# Deploy jar to the maven internal repository

Tags: windows, maven-3

I have created a maven internal repository. I am having jars that were not created using maven i.e. there is not pom.xml file for them. I need to deploy this jar to the internal repository that I have created. For this purpose i used mvn deploy:deploy-file.
Following is the command that i have used -

**mvn -X deploy:deploy-file -Durl=scp://localhost/my-repo/ -DrepositoryId=localhost -Dfile=temp.jar -DgroupId=com.myorg -DartifactId=temp -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=test -DgeneratePom=true -DgeneratePom.description="temp test" -DrepositoryLayout=default -DuniqueVersion=false**

I am using windows xp and apache-maven-3.0.3. I am getting following error -

**"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository localhost (scp://localhost/commons-logging/) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory"**

I have never used scp on windows as I have worked on linux machines and I also dont do i need to install it for achieving this task then where can i install it from and how to overcome the error that I am facing. Please guide me regarding this issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: The error is resolve we just need to copy the jars into the maven_install_dir/lib/ext/. Following are the jar files

1. jsch-0.1.38.jar
2. plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6
3. wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-7
4. wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-7

We need to do this because as we are trying to deploy a jar which is not created using the maven and as it doesnt have a pom.xml, so we cannot add the <build> <extensions>... </extensions> </build> that are required to execute the wagon-ssh. Hence we are directly adding them to the mvn/lib/ext/.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what this repository is.  If the repository in question is your local machine repository you can do this:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.transaction -DartifactId=jta -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0.1B -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

If the repository is something like Nexus, then use their UI to upload the artifact and it will create a pom for you.

Answer (score 1):

`mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=scp://d8u.us/home/hd1/public_html/maven2 -DrepositoryId=localhost -Dfile=yourwar.jar -DgroupId=us.d8u -DartifactId=yourwar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true  -DrepositoryLayout=default -DuniqueVersion=false` works for me. I merely needed to create the `maven2` directory under my home directory and set the appropriate permissions for the web user and cribbed off [Mr. Sierra](http://stuartsierra.com/)'s blog, where he has kindly provided near-working [instructions for my case](http://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to deploy a proprietary third party jar into our internal repository over ssh. I ended using a small Ant script, I felt it was safer than fiddling with the Maven classpath.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Maven Deploy" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">

  <property name="repository.id"  value="myrepository"/>
  <property name="repository.url" value="sftp://dev.example.com/var/www/mvn"/>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="target/lib"/>
    <get src="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" dest="target/lib" skipexisting="true"/>
    <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" classpath="target/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>

    <artifact:install-provider artifactId="wagon-ssh" version="2.2"/>
  </target>

  <target name="deploy" depends="init">

    <echo>Deploy a jar to the Maven repository:</echo>
    <input addproperty="groupId"    message="groupId:"/>
    <input addproperty="artifactId" message="artifactId:"/>
    <input addproperty="version"    message="version:"/>
    <input addproperty="file"       message="file:" defaultvalue="${artifactId}-${version}.jar"/>

    <artifact:mvn failonerror="true">
      <arg value="org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.6:deploy-file"/>
      <arg value="-DgroupId=${groupId}"/>
      <arg value="-DartifactId=${artifactId}"/>
      <arg value="-Dversion=${version}"/>
      <arg value="-Durl=${repository.url}"/>
      <arg value="-DrepositoryId=${repository.id}"/>
      <arg value="-Dfile=${file}"/>
    </artifact:mvn>

  </target>

</project>
```

Just type `ant deploy` and specify the groupId, artifactId and version of your file.